# How do I make turtles bounce off the world boundary in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a box-bound world in Netlogo and my turtles are moving the way I want but some get stuck to the wall, which draws others in (I'm using the Flocking model as the backbone) until all turtles are stuck facing a wall and stop moving. I tried including a wall_jump in Go, but it doesn't help once there are too many flockmates up against the wall, so I put another block in to ask flockmates to bounce off the wall but it didn't seem to have any effect. If you want to recreate the entire issue, open the flocking model and close the world boundaries in.

How have others solved this issue?

```
 to wall_jump
  ifelse any? flockmates 
  [
   if ycor >= max-pycor * 0.95  [set heading (random-normal 180 2)] 
   if xcor >= max-pxcor * 0.95 [set heading (random-normal 270 2)]  
   if xcor <= min-pxcor * 0.95   [set heading (random-normal 90 2)]          
   if ycor <= min-pycor * 0.95   [set heading (random-normal 0 2)]           
  ]

  [if ycor >= max-pycor * 0.95    [set heading (random-normal 180 2)] 
   if xcor >= max-pxcor * 0.95   [set heading (random-normal 270 2)]  
   if xcor <= min-pxcor * 0.95   [set heading (random-normal 90 2)]          
   if ycor <= min-pycor * 0.95   [set heading (random-normal 0 2)]           
  ]
  end
```

Comment: What's the difference between your if and your else statement?

Comment: flockmates is a carry over from the "flocking" model I'm basing this off of, it's owned by the turtles. Basically they identify turtles near them as flockmates, then determine their new heading based off the average heading of their flockmates. What I was going for with that ifelse statement was to say basically whether you have any flockmates nearby or not, decide on a new heading in the same way because you're stuck against a wall. It doesn't work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solved in the Random Balls model (in the NetLogo models library):
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/RandomBalls

Although not directly related to your problem, it seems you might find it interesting as well to look at the Heroes and Cowards Model, which produces wall clustering (in Cowards mode):
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/HeroesandCowards

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards those models Alan. I adjusted my model to fit the requirements of their solutions, which were to simply put 
'if abs pxcor = max-pxcor
    [ set heading (- heading) ]

  if abs pycor = max-pycor
    [ set heading (180 - heading) ]'

which works, but only if your origin is at the center (mine was at a corner). I ended up telling my turtles to spawn on the left edge anyways through a secondary function that I can share if anyone needs it